# No display when graphics card installed

Tags: hardware-failure

I have received a computer from a friend (he upgraded and graciously gave me his nice/older machine.) He says other than "rare hangups on start," he has had no problems. He salvaged the graphics card out of his machine, but left me the rest.

**Specs:**

- i7-3770K
- 16GB HyperX RAM
- Gigabyte G1 Sniper 3 Mobo
- AMD Radeon RX560 (i'm on a budget.)
- 850 watt corsair PSU

**Here's what I'm experiencing**
Whenever the graphics card I purchased is installed/plugged in, the machine doesn't POST. The error on the LED is 97, which for this MB basically means "No output device." When I boot without the card, onboard video works.

**What I have tried**

- Resetting the CMOS
- Installing a different RX560 (thought the first one was just DOA, but I'm getting the same result with both cards)
- Cycling through my sticks of ram in the first slot.
- Installing each card in each PCIE slot

The machine worked just fine.. he used it daily to game and stream before he upgraded. My gut is kind of telling me that Occam's Razor applies here, and I just may have purchased two dead video cards.

Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: What motherboard is it? Or make and model of PC?

Comment: I hope you verified this machine could POST before you purchased it.  Have tried to restore the UEFI firmware to their defaults?

Comment: @Moab Gigabyte G1 Sniper 3.

Comment: @Ramhound I know it did, I saw him use it frequently. I have reset the CMOS but I'm unfamiliar with UEFI. Is there another firmware reset?

Comment: "rare hangups on start," there is your problem, ask him for a refund, he is not a friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I purchased a USB thumb drive and used it to install the latest BIOS for this motherboard. The machine now boots without error.